# quickfix UtcTimeStampField python

Tags: python, quickfix

How can i create a such fix field in python ?

If I do this :

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now() + relativedelta(days=1)
f = fix.UtcTimeStampField(126, dt)
print f
```

it just uses the default constructor in the first line and so I get the current date time in second line.

I need to access to the fix type UtcTimeStamp but I do not know how to access it in python.

I checked the date dt, it is perfectly fine.

It seems to me that the type FIX::UtcTimeStamp is just not supported in python.

Comment: jazzpi, do you need something more ?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the value from a message received, or create this field in a new message which you will then send?

Comment: In the end, I converted the entry I needed from UTCTIMESTAMP to STRING to make it work. I think the UtcTimeStampField type is not supported in quickfix python.